# google app script get script request URL

Tags: google-apps-script

In google script I need get this script url.
It has url like `"https://script.google.com/macros/s/somecharshere/exec"`

And I need get this url (and send in responce).

But I found no way to do this. All I can is get query params via e.parameter.*, but not full request url.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()

Comment: Tnks, this help. In addition, I had to perform actions from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421055/. Now its worked.