# Google apps script for spreadsheet return URL

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to make a custom function return the same output like

```
=HYPERLINK(url, [link_label])
```

Basically, I am computing a URL inside the custom function and want to return a hyperlink with a specific link label. So far I can only return a link of the form.

```
function calLink() {
  return 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE [...]'
}
```

This puts a valid link into the spreadsheet but does not allow me to specify a label for that link.

Comment: I don't think so :-/

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Use [Range.setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula).

```
function addHyperlink() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1);
  var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
  cell.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("www.google.com","google")');
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error `Error
You do not have permission to call setFormula`

Comment: Yup. That's listed in the ["Common errors" section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#common_errors) of the Troubleshooting guide. Has also been [asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421055/). I'll leave the exercise to the reader...